Cashing a check
So, my bf and I received a check in both of our names for our deposite back and I cashed the check but didn’t tell him and then he went and tried to cash it and a couple days later it didn’t go through. My bf doesn’t know I cashed it. I’m really nervous if he reports the check as fraud but it was really me that cashed it. What will happen? I know I need to tell him.

How were your names written in? With "and" or "or"? If it says "or" and you were not intentionally trying to hid this from him, you should be fine...

How could you both cash it? When you cash a check at a bank, you have to give them the check and he won't have it. If you use a mobile deposit app, you have to endorse the back of the check, and he should be able to see this endorsement when he tries to do it again.

(assuming US but probably similar in many other countries)

I know I need to tell him.

There's your answer. You will be found out eventually. The sender's bank will get the check with your signature (and his if you forged that) that they will probably show the boyfriend as proof.

+1 This could go from honest mistake to criminal investigation really quickly, so make sure you tell him ASAP
